# Max and Group by functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, group-by, max, common-table-expression

my sql got a bit rusty and I was wondering if there is a simple solution for my ask. I'm trying to get two unique UUIDs with with MAX ModifiedTime. Below is my code that I tried to simplify as much as possible. My goal is to get unique UUID with its MAX ModifiedDate along with other two associated columns- desired output 2 rows.

```
SELECT [UUID],[Description],IsHLVE,ModifiedTime
FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents
WHERE UUID in ('0b666564-38af-4cc2-9a58-58f9b57244b1','4b6080ea-5c13-4f03-8967-a6beb71e80c4')
ORDER BY UUID,ModifiedTime
```

[image: Output for the code above]

I tried to group by all columns and do max which doesn't work properly since my "description" and "IsHLVE" have different values.

```
select [UUID],[Description],IsHLVE,MAX(ModifiedTime)
FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents
WHERE UUID in ('0b666564-38af-4cc2-9a58-58f9b57244b1','4b6080ea-5c13-4f03-8967-a6beb71e80c4')
GROUP BY [UUID],[Description],IsHLVE
ORDER BY UUID
```

[image: Output from my try]

I believe I need some kind of temporary table first and then join it back?
My desired output should have two unique UUIDs with its max date including all associated columns.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify! [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh apologies, when you click the image it gets bigger and can be read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-query and inner join takes care of this.

```
SELECT
    t1.uuid
    ,t1.Description
    ,t1.IsHLVE
    ,t1.modifiedtime
FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents as t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(modifiedtime) as modifiedtime
        ,uuid
    FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents
    GROUP BY uuid
) as s on t1.uuid = s.uuid and t1.modifiedtime = s.modifiedtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents AS t 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT [UUID],MAX(ModifiedTime) AS LatestModifiedTime
 FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents
 WHERE UUID in ('0b666564-38af-4cc2-9a58-58f9b57244b1','4b6080ea-5c13-4f03-8967-a6beb71e80c4')
 GROUP BY [UUID]
) AS latest ON latest.UUID = t.UUID AND latest.LatestModifiedTime = t.ModifiedTime
ON latest.UUID
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the max modification time per UUID:

```
select [UUID],MAX(ModifiedTime)
FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents
WHERE UUID in ('0b666564-38af-4cc2-9a58-58f9b57244b1','4b6080ea-5c13-4f03-8967-a6beb71e80c4')
GROUP BY [UUID]
```

Now you can get the data you want by selecting the values, and JOINing them:

```
select [UUID],[Description],IsHLVE,MAX(ModifiedTime)
FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents tCSPI
INNER JOIN (
   select [UUID],MAX(ModifiedTime) as MMT
   FROM tblConstructSecureIntelProjectIncidents
   WHERE UUID in ('0b666564-38af-4cc2-9a58-58f9b57244b1','4b6080ea-5c13-4f03-8967-a6beb71e80c4')
GROUP BY [UUID]
) sub ON sub.UUID = tCSPI.UUID AND sub.MMT = tCSPI.ModifiedTime
```